# strange sqlite error in gosqlite (golang)

Tags: sqlite, go

I got a strange error and can't find out whats going wrong.
I use this function to save an incoming message:

```
func (mdb *MailDB) SaveMail(mail *Mail){
    conn, err := sqlite.Open("maildb.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Unable to open the database: ", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    insertsql := fmt.Sprintf(`INSERT INTO mails (sender,subject,text,time) VALUES ("%v", "%v", "%v", %v) ;`,
                    mail.Sender,mail.Subject,mail.Text,time.Now().Unix())
    err = conn.Exec(insertsql)
    if err!=nil {
        log.Print("maildb insert fail @exec: ",err)
        log.Print(insertsql)
        return
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
2012/05/09 10:10:20 maildb insert fail @exec: SQL error or missing database: unrecognized token: """
2012/05/09 10:10:20 INSERT INTO mails (sender,subject,text,time) VALUES ("wLrOBizTcmS1MlqeXydUK9U6YJQ=", "abc", "321
", 1336551020) ;
```

(after 321 is an '\n' i dont know why its ommited here)

The strange thing is, that I can send the copy'n'pasted query in an sqlite console without problems.

do someone see whats going wrong?
please help!

Comment: Isn't there a problem with the \n or any other char in one of the mail's fields ? Using a prepared statement would be the solution in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is using `"` to delimit string literals while this is not standard SQL syntax, and not supported by sqlite as well.
To cite [its manual](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL

So the obvious fix should be using

```
insertsql := fmt.Sprintf(`INSERT INTO mails (sender,subject,text,time) VALUES ('%v', '%v', '%v', %v) ;`, ...)
```

Also note that constructing the SQL statements like you do is naive and is subject to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  The proper way would be to first [create a prepared statement](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), then [bind its parameters to actual values](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) and then executing it.  I have no experience with Go bindings to sqlite so I can't tell if they support the API I referred to but I think you should try to investigate this.

Comment: using singlequotes doesnt solve the problem. i'll search how to use sqlite.prepare from go